# Editing jira issues in a grid

Tags: jira

I am looking for a plugin that will allow me to edit searched jira issues in a grid - much like excel. Couldn't really find one in the [jira market place](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/app/jira) section or on google. So question 1 - is there a plugin (free or paid) that I can use to do this.

I also looked at what it would take to create a custom plugin to support this functionality. I looked at [Jira Search Request View](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Search+Request+View+Plugin+Module). I was wondering if we can use this with a view that allows editing of the individual fields displayed in the search grid. I will have to figure out the details on how inline editing would work and how stuff would get saved, but at a high level does this sound plausible?

Note - This approach may sound naive, but I have no background in doing development on Jira API

Answer (score 0):

With JExcel  you can edit JIRA issues just like in Excel.

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.moresimp.jexcel

I hope it helped,

Regards,
Janos